# Can non-dairy creamer be used to make desserts like rice pudding?

Tags: substitutions, milk

I've used Soy Milk before, but never tried Non-dairy creamers - any help?

What about other type of pudding?

Answer (score 4):

I think it will work; you aren't really using any "fancy" properties of milk when you make rice pudding, it is mainly just serving as a liquid medium for the starch from the rice to thicken. Not saying it will taste great or be great for you, I think the soy milk, rice milk or almond milk would be more pleasant non-dairy choices, but I think it will work.

Comment: Agreed. It'll taste pretty grim, but it will work in the sense that it will behave similarly.

Comment: Don't forget coconut milk/water

Answer (score 2):

Non-dairy creamers are truly disgusting products.  Read the ingredients.  They're a horrid combination of sodium caseinate (chemically processed milk protein), artificial flavors, trans-fats, mono and diglycerides (gelatin), phosphoric acid, sodium alumionosilicate (anti-caking agent), corn syrup and stabilizers.

You might have found a better brand, or a vegetarian/vegan brand, but if you're using any of the standard grocery store brands, please don't.  Try some almond milk instead.

Comment: chemically processed milk protein - dairy. Isn't it amazing how corporations are legally allowed to lie?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't surprise, or even really bother me any more.  I assume that corporations sell things, and the only solution is education.  It really baffles me that more people don't read (or care about) labels:  I take that as the shopper's responsibility. Good brands *do* make it clear what their products are (or more likely 'are not') made of.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! I use So Delicious coconut milk creamer all the time for making rice pudding. You can also use canned coconut milk for a very delicious coconutty-tasting (although high-fat) rice pudding!